# I am getting an error, The method '*' was called on null

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have created a button class that extends a stateless widget for creating a customized button widget. I have used this button to create buttons in a class and it worked perfectly fine. But, when i tried to create a button in an another class, using the same button widget, i got an error,'The method '*' was called on null and RenderFlex overflowed' which i could not get why is it appearing. Can somebody help me, what and where did i do the blunder.

**This one is the button widget**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:group_project/ui/size_config.dart';
import 'package:group_project/widgets/responsive_widget.dart';

// Button Widget
class Button extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final String btnName;
  final double height;
  final double width;
  final Color buttonColor;
  final Color iconColor;
  final double iconSize;
  final Color textColor;
  final double btnTextSize;
  Border border;
  BorderRadius btnBorderRadius;
  MainAxisAlignment mainAxisAlignment;
  CrossAxisAlignment crossAxisAlignment;

  Button({
    @required this.icon,
    @required this.btnName,
    this.height,
    this.width,
    this.buttonColor,
    this.iconColor,
    this.textColor,
    this.border,
    this.mainAxisAlignment,
    this.crossAxisAlignment,
    this.btnTextSize,
    this.iconSize,
    this.btnBorderRadius,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      height: height,
      width: width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: buttonColor,
        border: border,
        borderRadius: btnBorderRadius,
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: mainAxisAlignment,
          children: [
            Text(
              btnName,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: btnTextSize * SizeConfig.textMultiplier,
                color: textColor,
              ),
            ),
            Icon(
              icon,
              color: iconColor,
              size: iconSize * SizeConfig.imageSizeMultiplier,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**This is the class where I got the error.**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:eva_icons_flutter/eva_icons_flutter.dart';
import 'package:group_project/ui/size_config.dart';
import 'package:group_project/widgets/widgets.dart';
// import 'package:group_project/data/data.dart';
// import 'package:group_project/widgets/product_carousel_widget.dart';

class ProductsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProductsPageState createState() => _ProductsPageState();
}

class _ProductsPageState extends State<ProductsPage> {
  Size size;
  bool visible = true;

  void isVisible() {
    if (visible == true) {
      visible = false;
    } else {
      visible = true;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xfff0f0f0),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 233.33 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Image(
                      image: AssetImage('images/jacket.jpg'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Stack(
                    children: [

//                      Products description
                      Visibility(
                        visible: visible,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 40.0, 10.0, 10.0),
                            height: 400,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
//                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
//                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
                              color: Colors.blue,
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      'Iphone Pro Max'
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Rs. 125000'
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 20.0,
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      '(Used)'
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Condition: Good'
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 20.0,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'This is iphone 11 pro max, 64 GB variant. The size of the mobile phone is 6.5 inches. Released 2019, September ',
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 20.0,
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  children: [

// This is the button where exactly I am getting the error
                                    Button(
                                      height: 25 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                                      width: 80,
                                      icon: Icons.shopping_cart,
                                      btnName: 'Add',
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),

                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      FlatButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            isVisible();
                          });
                        },
                        child: Button(
                          icon: EvaIcons.chevronDown,
                          btnName: 'Show Description',
                          height: 25.0 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          buttonColor: Colors.blue,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          btnTextSize: 8.0,
                          iconSize: 20,
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          iconColor: Colors.white,
//                          btnBorderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Row has no defined height or width.  Try wrapping your row in an Expanded widget.

This also why you're getting the null reference exception.  You're sizeConfig (Which I assume is based off of MediaQuery.of(context).size)  Gets it's context from it's parent widget and since a Row widget doesn't define (It is a flexible widget) height or width, it will return null for size.  Expanded will tell the Row to set its size to all available space.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it with Expanded Widget when using inside a Row or Column

```
Expanded(
           child:   Button(
                                      height: 25 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                                      width: 80,
                                      icon: Icons.shopping_cart,
                                      btnName: 'Add',
                                    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SingleChildScrollView(child: Container(...));}
```

surround your code with SingleChildScrollView that's why render flex error is showing

for the '*' is called on null error click on the run button at the bottom of android studio and look at the log and click the link with ProductPage.dart and it will take you to the line where the error happens

Answer (score 0):

**Try giving it a width or wrapping with a Expanded**

It is given infinite width because **MediaQuery** is always given the context of it's parent, and in this scenario it gets it from Row widget which doesn't have a defined width. Neither does a Column widget have a defined height. That's why it's giving the error.

Wrapping it with Expanded widget will make the Row take all of free space.